# Rear camera and flash tourch is not working!!on Nokia 3.1

Tags: camera

I am not able to use Rear Camera and Flash Light in My Nokia 3.1. Front Camera Works Well. When I open Camera App, by default it Opens with Front Camera. Rear Camera Option is Not Found. (Front Camera works Perfectly Fine)

Even when i opened WhatsApp and Take a pic, only front camera is shown. No Button to switch To Rear Camera. (Front Camera works Perfectly Fine)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an hardware defect with the camera. If a restart doesn't fix it, then you can should bring it to a Nokia Care point.